# Not able to query by lastprocessedTime using MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm new to MongoDB , please help me to get this piece of code return data.
String dateString = "Sun Jul 05 00:00:00 IST 2020";

```
    BasicDBObject queryDB = null;
    
    final DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

    // The parsed date
    final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, inputFormat);

    // The output format
    final DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String date = outputFormat.format(parsed);
    queryDB = new BasicDBObject("lastProcessedTime", //
            new BasicDBObject("$gte", date));
```

note: mongo shell query runs fine with ISODate : db.xxx.find({ "lastProcessedTime" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2020-07-05 00:00:00")}})

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper formatting pattern as shown below to parse the date string you have `"Sun Jul 05 00:00:00 IST 2020"`. I am using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` (you can try `java.time` APIs also).

```
String dateStr = "Sat Jul 04 00:00:00 IST 2020";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
```

I am using MongoDB Java Driver v3.12 APIs for the query code:

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(Filters.gte("lastProcessedTime", date)).iterator();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document doc = (Document) cursor.next();
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```